# convert dd hh:mm:ss to integer

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a column in a char with a "dd hh:ms:ss" format is there any function or something to change it to an integer? (I'm using Oracle 10)

This is my full operation

(21/06/2012 20:33:00-21/06/2012 13:01:00)+(22/06/2012 10:29:00-2/06/2012 04:39:00)+(00 04:20:48)

The dates are in epoch but I have actually a fn to change them to datetime.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is a varchar and I need to add that time to another difference of dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [TO_DSINTERVAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions184.htm).
For example:

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + to_dsinterval('00 04:20:48') the_date from dual;

THE_DATE
-------------------
07/13/2012 04:20:48
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
invResult  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;

invResult  := (TO_DATE('21/06/2012 20:33:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') -
               TO_DATE('21/06/2012 13:01:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) +
              (TO_DATE('22/06/2012 10:29:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') -
               TO_DATE('2/06/2012 04:39:00',  'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) +
              TO_DSINTERVAL('00 04:20:48');
```

That should get you close.

Share and enjoy.